# Do older players tend to never bluff?

Tags: texas-hold-em, nlhe

In cash no limit Hold’em, is there a pattern or behavior that older players don’t tend to bluff?

Comment: How come you reached this conclusion?

Comment: No, us old farts just bluff better.

Answer (score 4):

In general, if you are playing low stakes (1/2 or 1/3) I would assume that *all* unknown players don't bluff, unless they give you a reason to think otherwise.  If they are a bad player, their bluffs will likely be obvious, if they are a decent/good player, they know not to bluff you until they have seen you play for a few hours.

I personally would **never** try to bluff a player at low stakes *unless*:

- they showed me they are capable of folding top pair; this usually takes a few hours of play and sometimes multiple sessions to get a feel for
- they turned their range faceup and I am confident that they have very few calling hands.

To analyze the stereotype that *old players don't bluff*, I would say that it is a *dangerous* to assume this without any other information, other than the villain is **old**.  I have seen old people range from complete spewtard maniacs that blow through 10+ buyins in a few hours to old tight nits that play 1 hand an hour.

There are *much* better indicators to go off of, such as whether or not they are drinking (this implies they are loose and trying to "have a good time"), their general attitude, opening size, etc.  And honestly, I have yet to see an accurate "guide" for analyzing player stereotypes.  I have concluded in my (limited) experience that this is something that is developed over years of play, and not something that can be simply read in a book.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, older persons tend to bluff less. But there are older persons that bluff alot, and i dont think its a good strategy to assume a player falls into one category or the other without additional information.

A more important question would be, do old people tend to bluff less than they should? Even if a player bluffs once in awhile, if you know they underbluff in many spots, you can be profitable by laying down all your bluffcatchers. Its not always necessary to try to guess when he/she is bluffing in a particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

never bluff, maybe rarely bluff would be better.

if an unknown villain bets and a bluff is suspected - reduce the percentage 1% for ever year over 25years old.

you think the villian is bluffing 60% --  if the villan is 50 years old reduce that percentage by 25% - now there is a 35% chance.

Answer (score 0):

I have two tournament trophies. First and second both in 250 men tournaments.

I probably only bluff 1 in 20 hands. I love to play the occasional 3 + 4 5 shakes, any kind of running combinations in the middle of all the hands because it's crazy. They say they don't hit, but they sure do run a lot. I would much rather have shooting 6 7 then Jack King sometimes. As far as the bluffing, we mix it up.